# C# - Report rdlc add parameter dropdown box

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I´m new to Visual Studio Reports. I added a parameter to my report with a default value and a query to define the available values.
The parameter is working, my report is generated with the default values.

But how can I add a dropdown box to select the value from my parameter?

I think there must be a ootb dropdown box to select the value or not?

Answer (score 1):

What report viewer you're using? Web? Windows Forms? If you set your report viewer to display the arguments bar you'll get a simple interface for their editing.

Comment: I´m using Windows Forms. I don´t found a property like [display the arguments] for the report viewer. Where is this property?